# accessing clipboard via win32clipboard

Tags: pywin32

I am working on a project in which i have to continuouly check clipboard content. If clipboard content matches with certain specified data, then it should be deleted from clipboard.
After doing a lot of googling, I find out that it can be done easily by win32clipboard api.
I am using Python as a programming language.
Following is a code for file(CF_HDROP) format:

```
import win32clipboard
import win32con

def filecopy():   
    try:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        print win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_HDROP)
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Following is a code for text format:

```
import win32clipboard
def textcopy():
    try:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
        print data
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

I am calling above functions in a infinite loop.

Individual function works correctly. But the problem with win32clipboard is that,
after win32clipboard.OpenClipboard() command, win32clipboard lock the clipboard and only realise it after CloseClipboard() command. In between i cant copy anything in clipboard.

How can i solve this problem??
Any other suggestion are also welcome to achieve ultimate aim.

NOTE: Its not necessary to use python. You can use any other language or any other approach.

Answer (score 2):

An infinite polling loop (especially one without delays) is going to be a problem since there's no way to read the contents without locking.  Instead you should look into becoming a `Clipboard viewer` ([pywin32](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32clipboard__SetClipboardViewer_meth.html) and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), that way you are notified of the clipboard contents change and then you can inspect it (get it and get out).  If you google a bit on `pywin32` and `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD`, you'll find some python [implementations](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/source/browse/src/python/pywin32/PLATLIB/win32/Demos/win32clipboard_bitmapdemo.py).

Comment: i looked into win32clipboard.SetClipboardViewer documentation.
It says that the function adds the specified window to the chain of clipboard viewers.
i didn't understand it, so can u elaborate it??
Thanx a lot in advance.